# PSI Project Pubish takes long time

Tags: c#, psi

I develop a new Webpart used to update Project Server 2010 Project Custom field, the problem when my code Update and Publish the project it takes 3-4 min in PS job Queue and the project not appear during this time in Project Center and the system become too slow, but there is no errors and the Custom field update successfully.
**is there any way to avoid this delay?**

note :i have two server front-end and database server.

```
**`Guid sessionUid = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid jobUid = Guid.NewGuid();                   
PSProject.CheckOutProject(projectId, sessionUid, "Updating Custom Fields");
jobUid = Guid.NewGuid();                                                      
PSProject.QueueUpdateProject(jobUid, sessionUid, PSProjectDataset, false);
jobUid = Guid.NewGuid();                                 
PSProject.QueueCheckInProject(jobUid, projectId, false, sessionUid, "Updating CF");                                
PSProject.QueuePublish(jobUid, projectId, true, null);`**
```

Comment: Let me guess, Project Server runs atop SharePoint...

Comment: yes it is, with sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons why it works slow. E.g. Database server is slow - Publishing itself includes coping data from Draft database to Published, Project plan is pretty big - as bigger project as more time it takes to publish it, there are some event handlers which stops events queue for some time.

Here what I can recommend you to troubleshoot your publishing:

- Check Sharepoint logs using [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer). It will you all timings of phases of publishing - there are about 100 operations
- Check performance of all servers involved into into work on the project: one of the front end servers and database server: disk, CPU, network

And of course Microsoft recommends to install all the lates updates and hotfixes.